# Error in very little loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I have very little loop where `i = 2` and `L = 0`.  After `i` reaches zero, I find `i == 18446744073709551615` and my loop continues indefinitely.

```
int L = 0;
size_t i = 2;

while (i >= L) {
  // do some work here
  i--;
}
```

Why does this loop not terminate?

Comment: Sorry, but it looks you oversimplified your code. Post a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem please.

Comment: Unsigned integers are always greater or equal to zero.

Comment: `18446744073709551615` is `2^64-1` which implies that i is of type `uint64_t`. Now the loop iterates for `i == 0` so `i--` overflows and wraps around to the largest positive value representable with that data type.

Comment: @Jack yes, but how to fix it? How to stop my loop before `i ==  18446744073709551615 `

Comment: @Jack that's an answer, you should post it as an answer, not in comment.

Comment: @rel1x: just use a signed variable. You can't stop it if you want to execute it for `i == 0` because you have no way to detect overflow.

Comment: @Jack thank you so much! :*

Comment: @rel1x Improve your question please as requested. I'm willing to retract my down and close votes, but please ask within respecting our minimal quality standards here!

Comment: Use the most aggressive compiler warnings and I am convinced the compiler won't compile your code.

Comment: @AlBundy I doubt that a simple compiler level SCA would catch such flaw. It needs in depth analysis of possible code flows, which usually isn't done by the 1st level compiler.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `gcc` won't let you compile the condition in the `while` statement due to compare between `signed` and `unsigned`. This is already enough and should help to analyse the problem. When both variables would have the same sign then it works. All my projects can be only compiled with the `gcc` warnings: `-Wall -Werror -Wextra`

Comment: @AlBundy Well, as you might notice the types where not known actually at the point when I wrote my answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ oh, don't missunderstand me! I was **not** critizing you at all!

Comment: @AlBundy Basically I agree with you, no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You left us completely unclear about the types used in your sample, but from the behavior we might assume you actually have:

```
int L = 0;
size_t i = 2;
```

and the loop condition

```
while (i >= L)
```

fails on underflowing `i` with the `i--` operation.

That means you'll have the `18446744073709551615` value in `i` afterwards, which certainly is greater than `0` (`L`).

`unsigned` values never can be less than `0`, and your compiler should have spit out a warning about that fact into your face (depending on builtin SCA capabilities).

Comment: Hi! Sorry that I left you without an answer about types. Yes, I used `size_t i`. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `i` is an unsigned integer, therefore, always greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: Please write comments as comments, not as answers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry, fixed